# Check if a certain field exists in a list that is also part of a database?

Tags: database, shell, unix, awk

I'm trying to make sure 'shipped' belongs to 'part' and 'part' belongs to 'Cpu'

cpu.txt contains:

```
Cpu part
```

list.txt contains:

```
part brand price shipping shipped
```

I've already made sure 'part' belongs to cpu.txt by using:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' cpu.txt >> temp.txt
```

then use grep to compare input vs $1 column in cpu.txt.

Now my problem is making sure those other arguments belong to both 'list.txt' and 'cpu.txt'

```
./check.sh Cpu shipped
```

Sorry if it's a little unclear, I can answer questions.

Comment: Can you show real life examples of cpu.txt, list.txt, your expected output and your current script?

Comment: The question was answered correctly, sorry it's hard for me to explain it accurately. I'm glad konsolebox got it though. I would Vote Up but I'm working on my reputation. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}a[$2]~/shipped/{print $0}' list.txt cpu.txt
```